# how to read javascript variable var and then pass its value to objective-c

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, variables, uiwebview

I am trying to read the following variable from javascript:

```
var a_value = 5;
```

I have tried using the below in the - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView method:

```
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"function f(){ return a_value; } f();"]; //try 1
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"a_value"]; //try 2
```

but its coming as blank, I have already tested in the chrome inspector that this variable exists. If i try to get value of a dom element by using document.getElementById function that works but I can't read a variable.

Any idea why?

EDIT:

If I try the below:

```
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"alert(a_value)"]; //try 2
```

then alert gets the value but thats of no use as I can't show an alert and i need that value from alert box.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:
I had to add an empty string to the variable:

```
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                    @"function f(){ return ''+a_value; } f();"]; //try 1
```